# Como cambiar Default Directory Powershell SSH

Tags: powershell

estoy realizando una conexión remota desde powershell a una máquina UNIX via SSH.
estoy utilizando esta serie de comandos:

```
New-SSHSession -ComputerName IP "USUARIO"
Invoke-SSHCommand -Index 0 -Command "pwd"
Invoke-SSHCommand -Index 0 -Command "cd /test/test/test"
Invoke-SSHCommand -Index 0 -Command "pwd"
```

Cuando realizo esta simple prueba espero que en el segundo pwd me encuentre con la dirección:
/test/test/test
Pero me encuentro, obviamente en el directorio de home de mi usuario : /home/USUARIO

Mi consulta es la siguiente, hay alguna forma sin tener que modificar ficheros ni conexiones de establecer conexión en un directorio determinado.
O como plan B, es posible realizar este cd de forma permanente?
O es posible realizad un cd y posteriormente al estar alojado en el directorio ejecutar otro comando?
Gracias

(Por cierto, no puedo realizar una ejecución como /test/test/test/ejecucion.sh, necesito estar previamente en el directorio).

Gracias.